# How to define ANTLR4 lexer rules that don't match anything?

Tags: antlr, antlr4

I have lexer mode MESSAGESIZE_MODE which can match file size of type '10 MB'. I would like to forward this token as FILESIZE (in the default mode), so I can recognize this value in the visitor, so know I am dealing with file size string. This below works, however I need to define one dummy lexer rules FILESIZE which shouldn't match anything in the default mode. Is this the correct approach for this problem? If yes, how I can define lexer rules that doesn't match anything?

```
FILESIZE
    : '%never_match_anything_in_default_mode'
    ;

mode MESSAGESIZE_MODE;
    MESSAGESIZE_MODE_FILESIZE: INT WS+ (K B|M B) -> type(FILESIZE), popMode;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there's a better way to do that. You can define a `tokens { ... }` section which allows you to reference them inside `type(...)` calls.

In your case that would look like this:

```
lexer grammar YourLexer;

tokens {
  FILESIZE
}

...

mode MESSAGESIZE_MODE;

  MESSAGESIZE_MODE_FILESIZE
   : INT WS+ (K B|M B) -> type(FILESIZE), popMode
   ;
```

If you have more of these virtual tokens to define, separate them by commas:

```
tokens {
  FILESIZE,
  SOME_OTHER_TOKEN,
  YET_ANOTHER_TOKEN
}
```